# Subtract rows from a table, using subquery which may be empty

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
table: A
-----------
value
1
2
3

sub-query: B
-----------
value
2
```

I need (A - B).

The below query works when B is not empty. Output = (1,3) as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM A
JOIN B
ON (A.value != B.value)
```

However, when the sub-query B is empty, the JOIN does an intersection of A with an empty B, and the output is an empty result-set.

And if I use LEFT JOIN, it does not subtract the row containing value 2 from table A.

Is it possible to write a single query for (A - B), irrespective of whether B is empty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.value = B.value
WHERE b.value IS NULL
```

Comment: That was quick ... and it works perfectly. Thanks. I'll accept it as the answer after mandatory 8 minutes.